# cv2.createTrackbar pass userdata parameter into callback

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, callback

I read the doc about [cv2.createTrackbar](http://www.opencv.org.cn/opencvdoc/2.3.2/html/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#createtrackbar). It said that

> onChange – Pointer to the function to be called every time the slider
>   changes position. This function should be prototyped as void
>   Foo(int,void*); , where the first parameter is the trackbar position
>   and the second parameter is the user data (see the next parameter). If
>   the callback is the NULL pointer, no callbacks are called, but only
>   value is updated.

But I don't know how to pass userdata into the onChange callback in Python.

I define my callback function:

```
def callback(value,cur_img):
    cv2.GaussianBlur(cur_img, (5, 5), value)
```

I got the error:

```
callback() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Because it only passes the bar value parameter into the callback. 
But I really need the cur_img for cv2.GaussianBlur function. How can I pass cur_img argument into the callback ?

Comment: can you not declare cur_img on input(before callback is called) and get it inside callback as global variable?

Comment: It seems in Python we can't use the parameter `userdata` available to C++, the Python syntax provided n the linked page doesn't mention it actually.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a function closure using a lambda expression as the callback function. I had the same issue when wrapping up a player in a class, and wanted to use properties of my class instance. Snippet of a class method below.

```
def play(self):
     ... other code...
     cv2.namedWindow('main', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
     cv2.createTrackbar('trackbar', 'main', 0,
         100,
         lambda x: self.callback(x, self)
         )
     ... other code...

def callback(tb_pos, self):
    #tb_pos receives the trackbar position value
    #self receives my class instance, but could be
    #whatever you want
```

Comment: Brilliant solution! Note that only a lambda function would work. It cannot be replaced by an instance method, because instance methods require a 'self' parameter. Neither can it be a static function outside the class, because you also need the 'self' class scope. So the lambda function preserves the instance scope with the first `self` while currying the instance as a variable using the second `self`.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a partial function using functools' partial function [Python docs for partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial) and then the callback function will only take 1 arg. For example:

```
import cv2
from functools import partial

def callback(x, a, b=None, c=None):
  print(x, a, b, c)

def addTracks(window_name):
  cv2.createTrackbar(bar1_name, window_name, 0, 255, partial(callback, a='R', b='G', c='B'))
  cv2.createTrackbar(bar2_name, window_name, 0, 255, partial(callback, a='R'))
```

This is similar to using function closure but I feel it's simpler and neater.

Comment: For the absent-minded like me, the parameter name in the partial call and in the function definition must be the same.